# JavaFX textarea - Ctrl+z not working after textArea.setText("...")

Tags: java, javafx, undo

I observed that in JavaFX textarea, `Ctrl + z` (for undo operation) is not working after calling `textArea.setText("...")`. Before setText is called, the undo operation is working fine.

Is there any way to enable undo accross multiple `setText` calls?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use [`replaceText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#replaceText(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) instead of [`setText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setText(java.lang.String)).**

I looked at the code for [`TextArea`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) (and [`TextInputControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html)) and found that [`replaceText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#replaceText(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) takes care of saving previous "actions" whereas [`setText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setText(java.lang.String)) will not save previous actions.
So undo operation (using `ctrl + z`) works as expected when using [`replaceText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#replaceText(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)).